# trying to get --listen-tcp on xvfb-run

Tags: ffmpeg, xvfb

I am trying to following these instructions http://afterdesign.net/2016/02/07/recording-headless-selenium-tests-to-mp4.html for recording selenium tests.

However, when I try to connect to xvfb with the port, I get:

[x11grab @ 0x1e3b460] Cannot open display 127.0.0.1:44, error 1.
127.0.0.1:44: Input/output error

I have simplified the problem to this:
in one window:

```
xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num=44 --auth-file /tmp/xvfb.auth -s "-ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24" gedit
```

in another window:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -i 127.0.0.1:44 -codec:v libx264 -r 12 ~/test.mp4
```

gets

```
[x11grab @ 0x1e74460] Cannot open display 127.0.0.1:44, error 1.
127.0.0.1:44: Input/output error
```

which is the same response I get when xvfb is not running.

I found something that sounds like that problem here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1340432 However, it says that that was solved in version 1, and I am already on version 1.17 and I am on 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2.

Any ideas?

=== UPDATE ===

after Lauscher's answer, I have boiled the problem down to this:

When I do this in one terminal:

```
$ Xvfb :44 -listen tcp -ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24
```

I and do this in another terminal:

```
$ xdpyinfo -display localhost:44 | head -n10
name of display:    localhost:44
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    11804000
X.Org version: 1.18.4
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    6
```

one the other hand, when I do this in one terminal:

```
$ xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num=44 -s "-ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24" google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp
```

(or any other application, such as selenium tests)

I see this in another terminal:

```
$ xdpyinfo -display localhost:44
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "localhost:44".
```

So I have a work around, but I still can't connect to xvfb-run over tcp

Comment: I have the same issue, but strangely, `xvfb-run` works pretty fine within a docker container but not on the host.

Comment: Note the TCP listen port will be 6000 + display number, so for display :44 the listen port will be 6044 . [Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17846189/812973)

Answer (score 4):

I'm more experienced with Xvfb than with xvfb-run.
You can try to run Xvfb directly:

```
Xvfb :44 -auth /tmp/xvfb.auth -ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24
```

(Xvfb listens on tcp by default, you could disable it with `-nolisten tcp`)

Otherwise, the problem could be using ip 127.0.0.1, maybe it will work with a different ip. I'm not experienced with it, but it is possible to set up an alias ip for localhost in `/etc/hosts`. Also, any ip given by `ifconfig` should work.

Comment: thanks that worked.  I had to put `-listen tcp` on the end.  I guess they changed the default.  Then I just ran the test command in a third prompt with `DISPLAY=:44` at the start

Answer (score 2):

The key argument, that make the whole difference is `-ac` for Xvfb, which stands for ["disables host-based access control mechanisms"](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.xhtml)

The `--listen-tcp` will be also needed if you plan to access the X server from another machine.

So, the full example with `xvfb-run` will be:

```
xvfb-run --listen-tcp -s "-ac" -- your_command
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
xvfb-run -s ":99 -auth /tmp/xvfb.auth -ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24" ./run.sh & # launching xvfb in the background \
sleep 3 && # waiting for xvfb to be ready \
ffmpeg -y -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -i :99 -codec:v libx264 -r 30 /tmp/test.mp4
```

So the whole thing is about passing the server-num directly to `Xvfb` via `-s` argument instead of using `--server-num`. I didn't try with `--listen-tcp` though.

N.B: Do not forget to kill `Xvfb` after `ffmpeg` is done (with a `killall Xvfb` for example).

Comment: If you are using `xvfb-run` instead of `Xvfb` directly, why do you need to `killall Xvfb`?  `xvfb-run` is meant to do that, otherwise you would just use `Xvfb` directly. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xvfb-run.1.html